# Differences between varying syntax when calling a method on a list

Tags: python

If i have

```
things = ["Dog", "Zebra", "Cow"]
```

what is the difference between

```
things.pop()
```

and

```
pop(things)
```

does Python3.6 process them differently? Is there any difference between the two at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pop` is not a built-in Python function. Only `things.pop()` works in your example.

On the other hand, if you're asking about `list.pop(things)`, then yes it is identical to `things.pop()`.

Although `list.pop(things)` is slightly less readable than `things.pop()` and is therefore not recommended in general, `list.pop` can be useful when you use it as a function for certain iterator-based operations. For example, the following gives you a list of the last item of each sub-list of a list:

```
>>> a=[[1, 2, 3],[9, 8, 7]]
>>> list(map(list.pop, a))
[3, 7]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking a specific question about `pop`, the answer is trivial: there is no function named `pop`. So, if you try `pop(things)`, you'll get a `NameError`.

Of course you can always write your own `pop` function:

```
def pop(seq, *args, **kw):
    return seq.pop(*args, **kw)
```

And now, of course, `pop(things)` and `things.pop()` will do the same thing. But the difference is that the former is calling your `pop` function, which calls the method, while the latter is just calling the method.

---

If you're asking a more general question about whether Python supports [UFCS ("uniform function calling syntax")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax), where function calls like `f(x, a, b)` are automatically turned into method calls like `x.f(a, b)`<sup>1</sup> if necessary, then the answer is no, Python does not.

Some other languages do. Mostly these are C++ inspired languages, like D and Rust.<sup>2</sup> In C++, free functions are "part of the interface" of a type, and C++ has all kinds of complicated features like Koenig lookup, special-casing for operators, etc. to make this work, and UFCS is a much simpler and usually more readable way to do it.

UFCS makes less sense in a dynamically-typed language, but there have been periodic proposals to add it Python anyway. See [this mailing list discussion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2014-June/673412.html), for example.

The *opposite* direction, UMCS ("Uniform Method Calling Syntax"), where `x.f(a, b)` gets turned into `f(x, a, b)`, makes a bit more sense—when `x.f` lookup fails, this is an easy thing to hook via `__getattr__` (which fits naturally into Python's Smalltalk-inspired dynamic lookup). And there are libraries like [`funcall`](https://github.com/koji-kojiro/funcall) that you can play with if you're interested (although I don't know of any production-ready solution).

---

<sub>1. … or, maybe `type(x).f(x, a, b)`. These aren't quite the same thing, but for any *normal* type, like `list`, they'll have the same effect, as explained in [blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51226905/908494), and for types that do something weird so they differ, I think calling the unbound method may be more likely to be what you want.</sub>

<sub>2. There have also been proposals to add it to C++, going back to the C++0x days. I believe the current version is [Stroustrop's N4174](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4174.pdf), an incomplete survey/summary, and following up on it was deferred for C++17, but might be considered again.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> things = ["Dog", "Zebra", "Cow"]
>>> things.pop()
'Cow'
>>> pop(things)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pop' is not defined
```

So, yes, there is a difference. I wonder why you would think differently?